# Insert command with 3 table relation and update with aritmetic command sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner who need help of you all, this is my question 3 relational table, the first table is used to populate the data in the table to two (nama_barang & size) and the data in the second table (jumlah_barang) to populate the data in table three but following three tables filled in the second table, the data should be automatically reduced, its purpose jumlah_barang of table 2 will be reduced when jumlah_barang in three tables filled please help me, thank you very much

(table 2 jumlah barang -(minus) table 3 jumlah_barang)

The address for photo orders table and I made : http://phm-group.co.id/Untitled.png

```html
<?php
  include "conn.php";
//proses input berita
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$id_surat = $_POST[id_surat];  
$seri = $_POST[seri];  
$id_barang = $_POST[id_barang];  
$ukuran = $_POST[ukuran];  
$jumlah_barang = $_POST[jumlah_barang]; 
$kbth = $_POST[kbth];
$peminta = $_POST[peminta];
$tgl_keluar = $_POST[tgl_keluar];
include ("conn.php");
$query="INSERT INTO surat(id_surat,seri,id_barang,ukuran,jumlah_barang,kbth,peminta,tgl_keluar) VALUES ('$id_surat','$seri','$id_barang','$ukuran','$jumlah_barang','$kbth','$peminta','$tgl_keluar')";
$sql = mysql_query ($query);

?>
<form id="form1" name="input" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return cekdata()">
<table width="612" border="0" id="center">

<tr>
<td colspan="2">No Seri</td>
<td>:</td> 
<td><input name="seri" type="text" id="seri" maxlength="10" size="auto" value="<?php
include ("conn.php"); 
/*pertama kita panggil colom yang akan kita gunakan untuk ID kita dengan menyaring nilai maksimum */
$sql ="SELECT max(seri) as terakhir from surat";
//mengecek hasil atau value yang dihasilkan dari query yang disimpan pada variable sql 
  $hasil = mysql_query($sql);
//memecah table hasil query
  $data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil);
//mengambil cell atau 1 kotak bagian dari table yaitu cell id_anggota yang dialiaskan terakhir
  $lastID = $data['terakhir'];
  // baca nomor urut  id transaksi terakhir
 $lastNoUrut = substr($lastID, 3, 9);
  // nomor urut ditambah 1
  $nextNoUrut = $lastNoUrut + 1;
  // membuat format nomor berikutnya
  $nextID = "DWS".sprintf("%05s",$nextNoUrut);
// selesai,,, untuk memanggil ID otomatis ini  bisa memasangkan cara
// IQBAL emang keren
echo  $nextID;
 ?>" readonly="true"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">Nama & Merk Barang</td>
<td width="10">:</td> 
<td><select name="id_barang" id="id_barang">
<option value="0"  size="auto" > ----- Pilih Barang ----- </option>
<?php 
include ("conn.php"); 
$SQL = "SELECT id_barang,nama_barang FROM barang order by id_barang desc";
$hasil = mysql_query($SQL);
  $no=0;
  while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
  {
 $no++;
    ?>
 <option value="<?php echo"$rs[id_barang]";?>"> <?php echo"$rs[nama_barang]";?></option>
 <?php
 } 
?>
 </select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">Ukuran</td>
<td width="10">:</td> 
<td><select name="ukuran" id="ukuran">
<option value="0" size="auto"> ----- Pilih Ukuran ----- </option>
<?php 
include ("conn.php"); 
$SQL = "SELECT id_barang,ukuran FROM barang order by id_barang desc";
$hasil = mysql_query($SQL);
  $no=0;
  while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
  {
 $no++;
    ?>
 <option value="<?php echo"$rs[id_barang]";?>"> <?php echo"$rs[ukuran]";?></option>
 <?php
 } 
?>
 </select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">Jumlah Barang</td>
<td>:</td> 
<td><input name="jumlah_barang" type="text" id="jumlah_barang" size="auto" 
value="<?php "SELECT A.nama_barang, A.ukuran, B.jumlah_barang, C.jumlah_barang
              FROM barang A, gudangcawang B, surat C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN gudangcawang T ON C.jumlah_barang = T.jumlah_barang
     WHERE A.id_barang = B.id_barang"?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">Kebutuhan</td>
<td>:</td> 
<td><input name="kbth" type="text" id="kbth" size="auto"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">Peminta</td>
<td>:</td> 
<td><input name="peminta" type="text" id="peminta" size="auto"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">Tanggal Keluar</td>
<td>:</td> 
<td><input id="example2" size="auto" name="tgl_keluar" type="date"/>
<div class="picker inElement" id="example2-picker"></div> tahun-bulan-hari</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onClick="saveForm(); return false;"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You should migrate away from using `mysql_*` functions, as they have been officially deprecated and present a security risk if not used carefully. You should consider using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Terry - Thanks for the tips, because I am also still learning so thank you all, on the question of whether you can give me a solution?